# mongodb balancer won't stop

Tags: mongodb, migration

After I restarted my sharded cluster I noticed the balancer was not migrating any data anymore but the command `sh.isBalancerRunning()` always returned true.

I tried to to run the command `sh.stopBalancer()` and it stuck forever on:

```
sh.stopBalancer()
Waiting for active hosts...
Waiting for the balancer lock...
```

Checking on the config server locks here is the data:

```
configsvr> db.locks.find({_id: "balancer"})
{ "_id" : "balancer", "process" : "myserver.mongodb.com:27017:1452776409:1804289383", 
"state" : 2, "ts" : ObjectId("56cb817f2c4edd1226d6ae07"), "when" : ISODate("2016-02-22T21:45:35.360Z"), "who" : "myserver.mongodb.com:27017:1452776409:1804289383:Balancer:846930886", 
"why" : "doing balance round" }
```

Also, if I try to run `sh.startBalancer()` it times out:

```
mongos> sh.startBalancer()
2016-02-23T22:51:11.204-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: assert.soon failed, msg:Waited too long for lock balancer to change to state undefined :
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:15:14
assert.soon@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:200:13
sh.waitForDLock@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:171:1
sh.waitForBalancer@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:264:9
sh.startBalancer@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:146:5
@(shell):1:1
```

in the `sh.status()`:

```
balancer:
  Currently enabled:  yes
  Currently running:  yes
    Balancer lock taken at Mon Feb 22 2016 16:45:35 GMT-0500 (EST) by myserver.mongodb.com:27017:1452776409:1804289383:Balancer:846930886
    Balancer active window is set between 8:00 and 6:00 server local time
Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  5
Last reported error:  Connection refused
Time of Reported error:  Tue Feb 23 2016 17:27:26 GMT-0500 (EST)
Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
    No recent migrations
```

I have tried restarting the servers, stepping down primaries, changing the *locks balancer state* to 0 and running `sh.startBalancer()` and removing the balancer field from the locks db and trying to run `sh.startBalancer()` again with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end it was an issue with the server clocks been out of sync, for some reason the logs about this issue didn't appear until the next day.

Hope this helps someone with a similar issue :)

Comment: you just saved me hours of search.

Comment: happy to help @mattspain

Comment: Hi hassek, did you need to do anything or did the lock get removed automatically once the clocks were synced?

Comment: Hi @bettlebrox , to be honest I don't quite remember if I removed the lock manually from the sh db or if I restarted mongodb in general.

Comment: No worries, I restarted the config server and the lock magically disappeared!